# Hide Status bar On a Tablet Running ICS

Tags: android

i want to hide status bar in tablet ics in my application
When i include this code. `

> `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);`

then the app crashed,

Is there any way to disable the status bar..
Or please give me a suggestion for hiding home button press

Do anyone have an idea in this topic,please help me tackling this problem

Comment: please share the crash logs...

Answer (score 1):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, share us your code. But I think the reason is that you put this line after `setContentView(..)` and you need to put it before